# When an activity with "singleTask" launchMode comes to Foreground - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity with "singleTask" mode. when this activity goes to background by taping on home key or other application, which methods will be called if it backs to foreground?

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) with savedInstanceState != null
onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

I think because there is one instance of this activity, it doesn't need to save and restore its state and it retain its own state always. am I right?

Answer (score 2):

The sequence of methods that will be invoked is as follows,(*in case when Android has killed the process hosting the Activity while the application was in the background,* ) when Activity with singleTask mode comes in foreground:

1.onCreate 
 2.onStart 
3.onRestoreInstanceState and 
4.onResume

Below is sample code to demonstrate the concept: Activity Declaration in AndroidManifest.xml:  `<activity android:name="Second" android:launchMode="singleTask"></activity>`

```
public class Second extends Activity {

    EditText mEdit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imageview_not);     
        if (savedInstanceState!=null){
            Log.e("onCreate of Actiity", savedInstanceState.getString("editval"));      }
        mEdit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("Second", "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        Log.e("Second", "onStart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);        
        outState.putString("editval", mEdit.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Second", "onRestoreInstanceState");
        if (savedInstanceState!=null){
            Log.e("onRestoreInstanceState", savedInstanceState.getString("editval"));
        }
    }


}
```

For illustration purpose, I am just using Edit Text and Android saves its state during configuration change, or when user press HOME etc.

Note that `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` is called before an activity may be killed so that when it comes back some time in the future it can restore its state using `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

Also as mentioned by David in another Answer,If Android has not killed the process hosting the Activity, then bringing the task from the background to the foreground will not cause either onCreate() nor onRestoreInstanceState() to be called.

Comment: This isn't correct. If the task is simply moved from the background to the foreground neither `onCreate()` nor `onRestoreInstanceState()` are called.

Answer (score 1):

If Android has not killed the process hosting the `Activity`, then bringing the task from the background to the foreground will not cause either `onCreate()` nor `onRestoreInstanceState()` to be called. The `Activity` doesn't need to be created (it already exists) and the state doesn't need to be restored, because it hasn't been changed.

If, however, Android has killed the process hosting the `Activity` while the application was in the background, when the user returns to the application Android will create a new process for the application, create a new instance of the `Activity`, call `onCreate()` passing the saved instance `Bundle` as a parameter. It will also call `onRestoreInstanceState()` passing the saved instance `Bundle` as a parameter.

Comment: is there any way to know when singleTask activity comes to foreground again by poping intermediate activities

Comment: @RahulPawar Sorry I don't understand your question. Please give more details.

Comment: I just wanted to know when I'm launching the activity first time and when I'm getting back by popping in between activities, I got it by overriding two methods      onNewIntent and on onRestart